# Запрос подписчиков

Tags: instagram

Отправляю в коде запрос на сервер.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/follows?access_token={мой токен}
```

Работает только если просматривать самого себя, то есть писать вместо username `self`. Если ввести ссылку с `self` в браузере, то возвращается текст `JSON`, если же там будет `user-id` другого пользователя, то говорит, что страница недоступна: ссылка недействительна или же была удалена. В чем дело? Мне не хватает прав на просмотр? Как их тогда можно получить?

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что видимо ваше приложение находится в режиме 'песочницы' https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/ Вам доступны только ограниченные ф-ции API. Вы можете выслать инвайты в Ваше приложение ещё 10 пользователям и ставить "опыты" над ними(будут доступны все фунуции API). Для того, чтобы выйти из режима "песочницы" приложение должно быть одобрено. Отправить на рассмотрение - ManageClient - Edit - Go Live.